# Form validation with the server

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that I would like to perform http validation by checking if an email exists but it returns an error. This is my form:

On the form component

```
 constructor(
   private _formBuilder:FormBuilder,
    private _validationService:ValidationService
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
this.resetForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  email:['',Validators.compose([
    this._validationService.emailExistsValidator  //this returns an error
   ,Validators.required
  ])]
})
```

On the validationService

```
  constructor(
public _authService:AuthService  //tried also with private
 ){}

  emailExistsValidator(control){
  if(control.value != undefined) {
  this._authService.checkExists("email")
      .map(response => {
        if (!response) {
           return {'emailNotExists': true};
        }
      });
   }
}
```

On the _authservice (its a service)

```
checkExists(value:string):Observable<any>{
return this._httpclient.get(this.authurl+value)  //httpclient attches the headers
  .map(response => {
   return response
  });
}
```

Now am getting this error

```
Argument of type '((control: any) => void)[]' is not assignable to4
 parameter of type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '(control: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.)
```

What do I need to do more?

Comment: may be related: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9336. It contains example of new custom validation: http://plnkr.co/edit/8DsRqpHo4tH4MPYauWAu?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormBuilder-class.html

async validators is the 3rd parameter

```
email:['', [Validators.required], [
  this._validationService.emailExistsValidator.bind(this)
]]
```

Comment: still returns the error even after adding as thired param

Comment: The error now reads Cannot read property '_authService' of undefined, the original error dissapers

Comment: The error shifts to argument of type '((control: AbstractControl) => void)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn[]'.
  Type '(control: AbstractControl) => void' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.)

Comment: Ive removed the {{(control) => this._validationService.emailExistsValidator(control)}} out of the validators.compose to as third param(out of the compose) and now the error reads cannot read property _authservice of undefined

Comment: Try without compose and wrap the first validator with `[]` like in my updated answer.

Comment: Now error changes to cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: There is a `return` missing before `this._authService.checkExists("email")` - should be `return this._authService.checkExists("email") ...`

Comment: Glad to hear :D

Comment: Hi ,Please could you also help me solve  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929208/angular2-checkbox-with-primeng-fails