# Form asynchronous validation in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Am new to angular2 and i would like to validate an email address from the server but it fails

This is my form

```
this.userform = this._formbuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required], [this._validationService.emailExistsValidator.bind(this)]],
});
```

Then the _ValidationService i have
The validation service is a service with @Injector

```
  @Injectable()
   export class ValidationService{

  constructor(
private _authService:AuthService
  ){}

 emailExistsValidator(control) {
   if (control.value != undefined) {
    return this._authService.checkExists("email")
      .map(response => {
       if (!response) {
          return {'emailNotExists': true};
        }
      });
     }
  }
}
```

And in the authservice i have (which is another service performing the http requests)

```
@Injectable()
 export class AuthService {

checkExists(value):Observable<any>{
return this._http.get(this.authurl+value)
  .map(response => {
   return response  //this is either true or false
  });
 }

}
```

I have followed [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910470/form-validation-with-the-server)  in setting up my form but it fails

The error returned is

```
Cannot read property 'checkExists' of undefined
at UsersComponent.webpackJsonp.187.
 ValidationService.emailExistsValidator
```

What could be wrong

Comment: You need to provide more context for your code. Where is the `emailExistsValidator()` method located? How is `this._authService` instantiated?

Comment: Sorry ive updated the question all these are different services, this._authservice is instantiated in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this` should point to the `ValidationService`, `bind()` needs to be

```
this.userform = this._formbuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required], [this._validationService.emailExistsValidator.bind(this._validationService)]],
});
```

Comment: The other issue now comes in i would like to validate only after the user has completed entering the email, currently works on every key pressed, How do i do that

Comment: Just hide the validation error while you don't want the user to see it. Like `showEmailValidation:boolean = false;` `<input (blur)="showEmailValidation = true" ...>`