# Angular2 checkbox with primeng fails

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I am using angular2 cli and this is the way i have setup my form

In the component

```
export class UsersAddComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      role: ['', [Validators.required]],
      others: this._formBuilder.array([])  //for adding multipe form inputs
    });

   this.addNewUser();

  }

  initAddress() {
     return this._formBuilder.group({     
       sendcred: [''],  //checkbox needs no validation in my logic
        needs_reset: [''], // ''
        .....other fields here
    });
 }


  addNewUser() {  //this is called whenever add new user button is clicked
     const control = <FormArray>this.userForm.controls['others'];
     const addrCtrl = this.initAddress();
     control.push(addrCtrl);
   }
```

In the html template am using primeng checkbox like this

```
  <p-checkbox formControlName="needs_reset" label="User has to set password" 
   (onChange)="Onpwdchange()"></p-checkbox>

  <p-checkbox formControlName="sendcred" name="send cred"  label="Send user
 login credentials " (onChange)="Oncredchange()"></p-checkbox>
```

The methods `onpwdchange()` and oncredchange() just have a `console.log("clicked")`

Whenever i check the checkboxes am getting an error

```
this.model.push is not a function  //i havent implemented push method anywhere
```

Ive checked on [This primeng2 issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/549) but they advice use of `disableDeprecatedForms()` and `provideForms()` which are not available in angular2 cli

How do i solve this issue

Comment: `disableDeprecatedForms` and `provideForms` are ancient history (pre final)

Comment: so is there a work around in my issue

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Didn't do much with forms since months.

Comment: Okay thanks for your continued support

Comment: Primeafaces != PrimeNG

Answer (score 6):

According to PrimeNG documentation

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox

formControlName doesnt work with primeNG's checkbox.

So you need to do like this

```
<p-checkbox value="xyz" [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['name']"></p-checkbox>
```

if you want binary value true/false

```
<p-checkbox binary="true" [formControl]="myFormGroup.controls['name']"></p-checkbox>
```

Comment: Two days I've looked for to send "true" value. That 'binary' property solved the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: once I set `binary=true` the `formControlName=...` part works with PrimeNg 9.0.0

Answer (score 2):

1. Initialize your form value as follows

file.ts

```
this.infraestructuraServiciosForm = this.fb.group({
     ....
     complementarios : new FormControl('', []),
     ......
});
```

2. The following line avoids the error:

   ```
   this.infraestructuraServiciosForm.controls['complementarios'].setValue([]);
   ```

file.html

```
<p-fieldset legend="Complementarios">
            <body>
                <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">
                     <div class="ui-g-12">
                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                            <p-checkbox name="cpl" value="acerasBordillos" label="Aceras y Bordillos" formControlName="complementarios" (onChange)="haCambiadoAcerasBordillos(checked)"></p-checkbox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                            <p-checkbox name="cpl" value="soloBordillos" label="Solo Bordillos" formControlName="complementarios" (onChange)="haCambiadoSoloBordillos(checked)"></p-checkbox>         
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                            <p-checkbox name="cpl" value="telefonoFijo" label="Red de Teléfono Fijo" formControlName="complementarios"></p-checkbox>      
                        </div>          
                        <div class="ui-g-3">
                            <p-checkbox name="cpl" value="alumbradoPublico" label="Alumbrado Público" formControlName="complementarios"></p-checkbox>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>                                     
                </div>
            </body>
        </p-fieldset>
```